# SLURM accounting not collect "AllocCPUS"

Tags: slurm

SLURM accounting not collect AllocCPUS values (sacct shows zero in all values).  What could be the reason?
Nodes settings im /etc/slurm/slurm.conf is: `NodeName=node[1-72] RealMemory=64338 Sockets=2 CoresPerSocket=8 ThreadsPerCore=1 State=UNKNOWN`

Comment: you should probably add some more description to this question.

Comment: what is the value of `SelectTypeParameters` in your configuration?

Comment: I do not specify the `SelectTypeParameters` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Define something like

> SelectType=select/cons_res
>
> SelectTypeParameters=CR_CPU

in your slurm.conf